# for loop will only print last value and not entire list

Tags: python, for-loop, printing, spatial, arcpy

I am trying to create a for loop that prints out every item in the list, Removes the .shp and replaces it with projected.shp. However, it only creates the a shapefile for the last value in the list and not all of the elements. I am not sure if there's an issue in my for loop or if I'm improperly using the project_management. My code is:

```
import arcpy
import os

#establish spatial reference of selected feature class 
targetDesc= arcpy.Describe(targetFc)
targetSr = targetDesc.SpatialReference
targetSrName = targetSr.Name


arcpy.env.workspace = folderWorkspace
fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses() 

# List current feature classes in folder
for fcCurrent in fcList:
    fcOut = os.path.splitext(fcCurrent)[0]
    print (fcOut + "_projected.shp")
    fcCurrentDesc = arcpy.Describe(fcCurrent)
    fcCurrentSr = fcCurrentDesc.SpatialReference
    fcCurrentSrName = fcCurrentSr.Name 
    
for fcCurrentSrName in fcCurrent: 
    if fcCurrentSrName == targetSr:  
               continue
    if fcCurrentSrName != targetSr: 
        print ("Error Matching Spacial Reference")
else: 
           print ("Spatial Reference Matching Succesful!")
# Print all of the geoprocessing messages
print(arcpy.GetMessages())

#Run Geoprocessing Tool
arcpy.Project_management(fcCurrent, fcOut +"_projected.shp", targetSr)
```

The console returns:

```
CityBoundaries_projected.shp
CountyLines_projected.shp
Ferries_projected.shp
PopulatedPlaces_projected.shp
StateRoutes_projected.shp
Error Matching Spacial Reference
Error Matching Spacial Reference
Error Matching Spacial Reference
Error Matching Spacial Reference
Error Matching Spacial Reference
Error Matching Spacial Reference
Error Matching Spacial Reference
Error Matching Spacial Reference
Error Matching Spacial Reference
Error Matching Spacial Reference
Error Matching Spacial Reference
Error Matching Spacial Reference
Error Matching Spacial Reference
Error Matching Spacial Reference
Error Matching Spacial Reference
Spatial Reference Matching Succesful!
Start Time: Monday, May 24, 2021 11:58:41 PM
Succeeded at Monday, May 24, 2021 11:58:42 PM (Elapsed Time: 1.47 seconds)
```

However in file explorer only StateRoutes_projected.shp is created and not the others

Comment: Indentation makes sense

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
for fcCurrent in fcList:
    fcOut = os.path.splitext(fcCurrent)[0]
    print (fcOut + "_projected.shp")
    fcCurrentDesc = arcpy.Describe(fcCurrent)
    fcCurrentSr = fcCurrentDesc.SpatialReference
    fcCurrentSrName = fcCurrentSr.Name 
    
    for fcCurrentSrName in fcCurrent: 
        if fcCurrentSrName != targetSr: 
           print ("Error Matching Spacial Reference")
        else: 
           print ("Spatial Reference Matching Succesful!")
    arcpy.Project_management(fcCurrent, fcOut +"_projected.shp", targetSr)
```

Comment: in file explorer only StateRoutes_projected.shp (the last value)  is created into a new shapefile and not the others. This happens with your example as well. My professor says I have a logical error in my for loop but I just don't understand what it is.

Comment: Could you please share the full source code from top to end to test it by myself..

Comment: okay I've edited it above so that the full code shows

Comment: @JessicaLambert `arcpy.Project_management(fcCurrent, fcOut +"_projected.shp", targetSr)` this is the logic to rename file right?

Comment: yes to create the new shapefile individually for each item in the list with the target spatial reference and not the original one it comes with

Comment: The rename logic should be inside the for loop, you put it outside the loop that's why only the last value only changes..

Comment: It finally worked once I input the arcpy.Project_management(fcCurrent, fcOut +"_projected.shp", targetSr) after fcCurrentSrName = fcCurrentSr.Name (in that for loop) Thank you so much!

Comment: Great Good luck!